# NodeJS Error Stack Undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using node inspector and I noticed `new Error()` had undefined stacks.

If I assigned this value to a variable, that variable would show that the stack is undefined.

Interestingly enough, running `new Error().stack` produces a message with the proper stack.

Ideally these errors would have stacks by default so when I log I can know where to look.

I do not understand why this is happening and cannot find information on it. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Maybe, could you add some code? When does "`new Error()` [have] undefined stacks"? Not when you ran `new Error().stack`, apparently. As to sources of info, if you haven't see this, it's a good start: "https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html". I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because *[The string representing the stack trace is **lazily** generated when the error.stack property is accessed](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_error_stack)*

A small illustration:

```
function newError() {

  var error = new Error('ohhh')

  // See the contents of a _stack variable using the Inspector
  var _stack = '' + error.stack

}

newError()
```

Comment: But the question is: Why does the lazy generation go wrong? Under what circumstances does it not generate the stack at all even though it's being accessed? The link isn't much help here. The code snippet doesn't help either: it evaluates to `undefined` because `newError` has no `return` statement, not because of problems evaluating the stack.